# finding maximal weight of a sparse index set of an array

Tags: algorithm, indexing, dynamic-programming, recurrence, sparse-matrix

Consider for example `A [14,9,13,4,6,12,11,10]`. The index sets `{1,3,5}` or `{1,4,6}` are sparse. `{1,2,5}` are not sparse because 1,2 are adjacent.

The weight is done by the sum of all sparse index, for example `w(1,3,5) = 14 + 13 + 6 = 33`

How can I develop a recurrence for W(k) for every k, 0 <= k =< n let W(k) be the maximal weight of a sparse index set for the prefix A[1..k] of A?

How can I write pseudocode for a dynamic programming that computes `W(k)` for all `0 <= k <= n`?
Thanks to everyone.

Comment: do the index sets always have only three elements?

Comment: So in your example, W(7) would be the maximal non-adjacent sum from A[1] to A[7], which seems to be 14+13+6+11 ?

Answer (score 0):

suppose the array index for A is 1-based. W is initialized to be all zeros. W can be calculated as follow:

W[i]=max(W[i-1],W[i-2]+max(0,A[i]));

if the elements in array A are always greater than zero, max(0,A[i]) is not needed.